MySQL stored procedure throwing [42000][1064] you have an error in your SQL syntax on EXECUTE stat USING statement
I am writing a stored procedure that does the following:
In a given table v_Tablename, if the count of the number of rows in v_ColumnName that equal to v_Value is greater than 0, return true. Otherwise, return false. Some examples where this stored procedure can be used:

Return if exists a person in Person table (v_Tablename) where Age (v_ColumnName) is 23 (v_Value)
Return if exists an email in Employee table (v_Tablename) where Email (v_ColumnName) is testing123@gmail.com (v_Value).

This is my code:
create
    definer = root@localhost procedure CheckValueExists(
    IN v_Tablename VARCHAR(100),
    IN v_ColumnName VARCHAR(100),
    IN v_Value VARCHAR(100),
    OUT v_Exists BOOLEAN
)
BEGIN
  SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', v_Tablename,
                      ' WHERE ', v_ColumnName, ' = ?');

  PREPARE stat FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stat USING v_Value;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stat;

  GET DIAGNOSTICS v_Exists = ROW_COUNT > 0;
END;

No matter how many ways I format this, I keep getting these errors:

[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'v_Value;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stat;
GET DIAGNOSTICS v_Exists = ROW_COUNT > 0;' at line 13

I think it doesn't like EXECUTE stat USING v_Value, but I need this line because it assigns ? to v_Value to do the check.
ROW_COUNT > 0 also doesn't like > but this is how I check if the results is > 0, which tells me if there exists values.
Does anyone know how I can correct my stored procedure?

This is the problem:
EXECUTE stat USING v_Value;

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html says:

Parameter values can be supplied only by user variables...

This refers to MySQL user-defined variables, the kind with the @ sigil.
Local variables like the IN parameters and local variables declared in the stored routine with DECLARE are not supported as arguments to EXECUTE.
It might seem needless, but a way to get this to work is:
SET @v_Value = v_Value;
EXECUTE stat USING @v_Value;

The SET statement creates a user-defined variable with a similar name as your input parameter (the name of the variable doesn't matter, I just chose a similar name in this example).

Yep, SET @v_Value = v_Value;
EXECUTE stat USING @v_Value;
resolved the issue-thanks!
